# React native convert time into seconds

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Code:

```
var moment = require('moment');

<DatePicker
    date={this.state.selctedStartTime}
    is24Hour={false}
    showIcon={false}
    mode="time"
    format="hh:mm A"
    confirmBtnText="Confirm"
    cancelBtnText="Cancel"
    customStyles={{
      dateText: {
      fontFamily: 'HelveticaNeue-Light',
      fontSize:18,
      fontWeight:'normal',
      color:'rgb(0,178,192)',
      marginLeft:20
    },
    dateInput: {
        borderColor:'white'
    }

    }}
    onDateChange={(timeValue) => {
        this.setState({selctedStartTime: timeValue})
        var timeStart = moment(timeValue, "hh:mm A").format('HH:mm A');
        console.log('time:'+timeStart.getTime());
    }}
/>
```

I try to convert time into seconds to find out difference between two dates, but `getTime()` gives not a function error. What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

So when you do `moment(timeValue, "hh:mm A").format('HH:mm A')` it converts it into a string which represents the date in the format of `HH:mm A`.

Hence a string does not have a function of `getTime()`

Comment: var newDate = moment(Date(timeStart)).format('HH:mm A');
                              console.log('time:'+newDate.getTime());I converted string to date.getting same error

Comment: dude your var `newDate` is a string, you are not converting it to a date object, if you want seconds, try `console.log(moment.duration(newDate).asSeconds())` or `console.log(moment(newDate).asSeconds())`

Comment: console.log(moment.duration(newDate).asSeconds()) return zero seconds